Codeigniter 4 : BUG Data not inserted to database
I have a data problem where $data does not enter the pemesanan table. I have done dd($data) and the data is in array form. when I do $PemesananModel->save($data), the data is not inserted to the database. Please help me
Controller
Data is sent from product1() to view and and from the view sent to add_pesan
 public function produk1()
    {
        $model = new ProdukModel();
        $pemesananModel = new PemesananModel();

        $data['getProduk'] = $model->getData();
        $data['cart'] = \Config\Services::cart();

        $noAntrian = $pemesananModel->generateNoAntrian();
        $idKaryawan = 1;
        $idPemesan = "P" . date('md') . rand(3, 1);


        $data['id_pemesan'] = $idPemesan;
        $data['id_pelanggan'] = session()->get('id_pelanggan');
        $data['id_karyawan'] = $idKaryawan;
        $data['no_antrian'] = $noAntrian;
        $data['tgl'] = date('Y-m-d');
        $data['status_pembayaran'] = "cash";
        $data['status_pemesanan'] = 'Dalam Antrian';



        $data['nama_pelanggan'] = session()->get('nama_pelanggan');
        $data['no_hp'] = session()->get('no_hp');

        echo view('user/produk', $data);
    }

public function add_pesan()
    {
        $pemesananModel = new PemesananModel();

        $id_pemesan = $this->request->getPost('id_pemesan');
        $id_pelanggan = (int)session()->get('id_pelanggan');
        $id_karyawan = 1;
        $noAntrian = (int)$pemesananModel->generateNoAntrian();
        $tgl = $this->request->getPost('tgl');
        $status_pembayaran = $this->request->getPost('status_pembayaran');
        $status_pemesanan = $this->request->getPost('status_pemesanan');

        $data = [
            'id_pemesan' => $id_pemesan,
            'id_pelanggan' => $id_pelanggan,
            'id_karyawan' => $id_karyawan,
            'no_antrian' => $noAntrian,
            'tgl' => $tgl,
            'status_pembayaran' => $status_pembayaran,
            'status_pemesanan' => $status_pemesanan
        ];

        log_message('info', 'Data to be saved: ' . print_r($data, true));

        if ($pemesananModel->save($data)) {
            session()->setFlashdata('pesan', 'Berhasil Pesan');
        } else {
            $errors = $pemesananModel->errors();
            log_message('error', 'Failed to save data: ' . print_r($errors, true));
            session()->setFlashdata('error', 'Gagal Pesan: ' . implode(', ', $errors));
        }
        return redirect()->to('/produk1');
    }

View
Data received from product1 and sent to add_pesan
 <form action="/add_pemesanan" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_pemesan" value="<?= $id_pemesan ?>" class="hidden">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_pelanggan" value="<?= $id_pelanggan ?>" class="hidden">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_karyawan" value="<?= $id_karyawan ?>" class="hidden">
                <input type="hidden" name="no_antrian" value="<?= $no_antrian ?>" class="hidden">
                <input type="hidden" name="tgl" value="<?= $tgl ?>" class="hidden">
                <input type="hidden" name="status_pembayaran" value="<?= $status_pembayaran ?>" class="hidden">
                <input type="hidden" name="status_pemesanan" value="<?= $status_pemesanan ?>" class="hidden">
                <button type="submit" id="cartIcon" class="flex items-center p-4 bg-indigo-500 text-white font-semibold rounded hover:bg-indigo-600">
                    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"><?= $all_item; ?></i>
                </button>
            </form>

Model
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class PemesananModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'pemesanan';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_pemesan';
    protected $allowedFields = [
        'id_pemesan',
        'id_pelanggan',
        'id_karyawan',
        'no_antrian',
        'tgl',
        'status_pembayaran',
        'status_pemesanan'
    ];

    public function generateNoAntrian()
    {
        $lastOrder = $this->orderBy('id_pemesan', 'DESC')->first();
        if ($lastOrder) {
            $lastNoAntrian = (int)substr($lastOrder['no_antrian'], 2);
            $newNoAntrian = $lastNoAntrian + 1;
        } else {
            $newNoAntrian = 1;
        }
        return str_pad($newNoAntrian, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }

    public function getData($id = false)
    {
        $builder = $this->db->table($this->table);
        $builder->select('pemesanan.no_antrian, pelanggan.no_hp AS no_hp, pemesanan.tgl, pemesanan.status_pembayaran, pemesanan.status_pemesanan, pelanggan.nama_pelanggan AS nama_pelanggan, karyawan.nama AS nama_karyawan');
        $builder->join('pelanggan', 'pelanggan.id_pelanggan = pemesanan.id_pelanggan');
        $builder->join('karyawan', 'karyawan.id_karyawan = pemesanan.id_karyawan');

        if ($id !== false) {
            $builder->where('pemesanan.id_pemesan', $id);
        }
        $query = $builder->get();
        return $query->getResult();
    }

    public function getData_for_pelanggan($id = false)
    {
        if ($id === false) {
            return $this->findAll();
        } else {
            return $this->getWhere(['id_pemesan' => $id]);
        }
    }
}

Routes
$routes->get('/produk1', 'AdminController::produk1');
$routes->match(['get', 'post'], '/add_pemesanan', 'AdminController::add_pesan');

Database


What happens instead? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Previously I created a shopping cart feature using the cart-module library. when the user selects a product, the product goes into the cart variable (\Config\Services::cart();). When the user clicks checkout, the data is such as name, WhatsApp number, ID, product, then the data is sent to the checkout function but I made a coding mistake. I entered the data into two tables at once, namely the pemesanan table and detail_pesan. I also changed it to this coding but the $data is already there but it doesn't go into the pemesanan table because I want the pemesanan table to be filled in first

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it
